# About the difference between setState in function components and class components

Tags: reactjs

[image]

I need to use the extension operator to keep **[show]** in the true state, but the class component does not need it. I can directly use this. setState ({showIndex: any})

```
function Child(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            {[1, 2, 3].map(item => <button key={item} 
            onClick={() => props.callBack(item)}>{item}</button>)}
        </div>
    )
}

function Child2(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            {`hello react-${props.showIndex}`}
        </div>
    )
}

function Parent() {
    const [state, setState] = useState<any>({
        showIndex: 1,
        show: true
    })
    return (
        <div>
            <Child2 showIndex={state.showIndex}></Child2>
            {state.show && <Child callBack={(i) => {
                setState({
                    ...state, // 
                    showIndex: i
                })
            }}></Child>}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Parent
```

I want to know the difference between them

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, but if I understand correct, you need state on parent because in a tree, nodes cannot interact with each other. You need to a parent node for that. So in your case, to know what child is to be shown and which are to be hidden, siblings cannot do that. You will need a parent who is aware of their behaviour and based on that sets hide/ show.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, you are confused about the fact that, you need to pass this to update state:

```
setState({
    ...state, // 
    showIndex: i
})
```

The reason being, state is immutable, or "read-only", so you should replace it rather than mutate your existing state object.

In the code snippet above, it does two things:

#### 1. Make a shallow copy of original state object, using spread operator:

```
{
    ...state, // shallow copy
    showIndex: i
}
```

#### 2. Modify property:

```
{
    ...state,
    showIndex: i  // update object property
}
```

While this approach `setState({showIndex: 2})` is creating and passing a new object, but this way, you've lost your original data `state.show`. And typescript won't be happy about it, since the new object doesn't have the `show` property in it.

BTW, the use of `any` is a really bad practice, you might as well omit it and let typescript infer the type of state automatically:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({ // no need for "any", the type is infered as the object
        showIndex: 1,
        show: true
})
```

Then you won't be able to do things like this: `setState({showIndex: 2})`

More info from Beta docs: [Updating objects and arrays in state](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useState#updating-objects-and-arrays-in-state)